# Wait for button animation to finish before destroying the parent fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Following is my Fragment Layout

```
     <LinearLayout

        <EditText
            .../>

        <com.example.android.view.ReshareButton
            .../>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I have an animation in the button code where a ✓ is displayed when I click on the button.

```
    public void setCurrentState(int state) {
    if (state == currentState) {
        return;
    }

    currentState = state;
    if (state == STATE_DONE) {
        setEnabled(false);
        postDelayed(revertStateRunnable, RESET_STATE_DELAY_MILLIS);
        setInAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_in_done);
        setOutAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_out_send);

    } else if (state == STATE_SEND) {
        setEnabled(true);
        setInAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_in_send);
        setOutAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_out_done);
    }
    showNext();
}
```

In my fragment `onSendClickListener()`

```
public void onSendClickListener(View v) {

     btnResharePhoto.setCurrentState(ReshareButton.STATE_DONE);

     hideKeyboard(getActivity(),etCaption);
     this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this)
             .commit();
}
```

**Issue:** The current fragment gets destroyed immediately and abruptly without waiting for the button animation to finish.

Want the following behavior once the text is written and I click on SEND button:

1. Keyboard comes down.
2. Button animation changes to ✓
3. Current fragment is destroyed and return to previous fragment (smoothly).

Currently, if I delete the `remove(this).commit();` I get the above-mentioned behavior, but then I need to press back to get back to previous fragment. How to do this after pressing the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put code
to handler's run callback like this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this)
         .commit();
        }
    }, RESET_STATE_DELAY_MILLIS);
```